# Combo Box Question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have added items in a combo box using datatable and rows. First it returned the value, and now it's returning dataRow. I don't know the reason why it's returning like that. Can anyone help?

```
string selectedValue = cbx_language.Text.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
string selectedValue = cbx_language.SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string selectedValue = cbx_language.SelectedItem.ToString`

This way, it does not matter what type of items you add using Items.Add/Insert.

Comment: Ya I got it.. Thanks All.. I assigned using dataset.. So i had problem.. Now i assigned using Display Member and Value..

Answer (score 0):

Is the value you are getting is System.data.datarow?
& if It is then Please set valueMember & DisplayMember properties of combo box to the column name u fetching in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string selectedValue = cbx_language.SelectedValue.ToString()
```